# "Image not found" Python2.7 PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, package

I am trying to run a basic QT application. I am running into an error and will provide the traceback because it will better explain than I can.

```
File "/Users/development/Desktop/python_workspace/mail-sorter/process.py", line 33, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.so
Reason: image not found
```

When I run it in python3.6 the script is fine. I have successfully ran it with python2.7 before, but somewhere out of the blue this error came up. All the files are where they are suppose to be. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have PyQt5 installed in python2.7?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yeah